# CartThrob - Getting started with inventory

Tags: cartthrob

I'm setting up a shop with CartThrob, with one product with multiple options. This is set up using Price modifiers. But now the customer has requested inventory to be updated through the shop. I've looked around, and tried to see how it's done, but to no luck.

I've tried setting up a text field called inventory, and set the Product Inventory Field Name to this field, but it won't change. I also tried to do it with a Matrix, but that didn't work either.

I have the "Update Product Inventory When Editing Order" set to Yes as well.

I've tried installing the "CartThrob Price Modifiers Configurator", but there is no column for inventory here.

Is there any Getting started guides for inventory in CartThrob? Because the docs are getting me nowhere.

**Edit:** I've even tried adding `{inventory:reduce entry_id="6" quantity="4"}` pointing to the product id, but still nothing.

**Edit2:** Okay, so setting the Price Modifiers Configurator field to the inventory-field gave me the inventory column, as I wanted, but it's still not updating the field after purchase.

Answer (score 1):

This is in the docs under **[Using Price Modifiers and Product Options](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/using_price_modifiers_and_product_options/)**.

> *inventory (Optional)* Your field will need to be mapped in CartThrob's
>   product channel settings as the inventory field to use the inventory
>   feature.

Comment: Correct. If you use the configurator fieldtype, an inventory column will appear once you map the field. If you use a regular matrix field, you will need to manually add a column called {inventory}.

Comment: That got the inventory column to show. But it still won't subtract for each purchase. Is there any way to debug what's happening after purchase?